# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) setup fail (0x8007046)

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I reformatted my PC after a windows(10 Home 64bit) update was interrupted. Then after drivers etc reinstalled, I installed:

- Installed Visual Studio Community
- Installed SQl Server Express 2017
- **FAILED** - to install SQL Server Management Studio 17.7

It seems to be the problem with the Visual Studio 2015 Shell (isolated) installation - trying to repair that fails:   "A setup package is either missing or damaged". You can only select "Skip package" or browse to find the files that are  missing, that aren't not shown at that stage, skipping results in this setup failed screen:

[image]

The VS installation only installs C++ Redistributable 2013 and 2017. Interesting, those 2013 version's of x64 and x86 that are installed are older versions than are required by the 17.7 install of SSMS, under their section: "installation tips and issues" here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

I have checked:

- adhered to all the "installation tips and issues"
- Latest .NET Framework is installed (4.7.. though you can't see this
  in add/remove programs
- formatted PC again to reinstall everything, just in case

no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok so I kept on googling etc.. two days of constant frustration.. but it seems to be an easy fix. Delete the Visual C++ 2017 in add remove programs - Visual Studio 2017 do not need those..

Then, the big answer.. thanks to KamilX64's answer at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce4466f8-f3c0-4e19-93df-7cea84eaf1fe/ssms-installation-stuck-at-installing-visual-studio-2015-shell-isolated-not-processing-further?forum=vssetup) link:

- Restart your computer (after a failed installation of SSMS).
- Empty your Temp folder (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp).
- Turn off Real-Time Scanning feature of your antivirus for some time.
  I suggest up to restart.
- Try again to install SSMS.

My AVG still stopped the Visual Studio Shell to install. I just disable it completely

Answer (score 2):

I ended up uninstalling V17.7 following the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

I then downloaded the full V17.6 and installed that version. It installed with no issues.

Comment: thats funny, I read many threads where people could not install any version.. going back to the 16's

Comment: I could not install any version of SSMS after the V17.7 update patch failed until I followed the uninstall instructions completely. After the uninstall, I tried installing the full version of V17.7 and it still failed. I had to do the complete uninstall all over again then installed the full V17.6 and that worked. The version now shows as 17.7 but I get a prompt that there is a newer version available. I'm leaving bad enough alone as I need any version of SSMS. I will wait for 17.8 and hope for the best.

Comment: I formatted my PC again, this time using original CD's for Win and drivers.. then installed SQL Server Express, SSMS 17.6 (thanks @BillB4) and then visual studio community... all works fine now.